# Enforcing limits on google spanner deletes

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner, google-cloud-iam

In order to prevent accidental loss of data from engineering mistakes, is it possible to limit the rows affected by a delete in google spanner?

There is a service account configured with roles/spanner.databaseUser, but in normal operation it should never delete more than a single row at a time.  In order to prevent serious application bugs that accidentally match more than intended, **is it possible to limit the number of rows deleted at a time by the service account?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it currently is not possible to enforce access rules in this manner.

As a soft workaround, you should wrap the delete operation in a helper method that only allows a single row delete and ensure your code only ever calls that helper method.